# How to make a model to carry only a boolean value without database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a settings page and one of them is called "Enable News" And it have to return a boolean value
What i want to do is to carry the value of this field and call it again in another pages like

```
if (model.Boolean == true)
{
 //Code
}
```

WITHOUT using database because this option is made for only 1 User

The purpose is to save this data in the model without database and be able to edit it later

Comment: You generally can't store data without a database. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If it's a one object model then maybe you can store it in a json file and load it using packages like `Json.NET`

Comment: @Arshia001 this option will be for only 1 user is that requiers a whole table ?

Comment: Yes it does. You certainly don't want to store it for only one user, you want to store it ***per user*** (as in, each user gets her own value), right? Then you need a table to store the value per user. The columns will probably look like this: (id, user_id, enable_news)

Comment: Not an answer, but `if (someBoolean == true)` always irks me. It's a waste of code, because you can just write `if (someBoolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing configurations can be done using `XML`, `JSON` and other formats according to the project requirements and what you're comfortable using.

`JSON` format is fairly simple if you have an object like

```
class UserSettings {
    public bool EnableNews {get; set}
    ...
}
```

Then you can simple use `Json.NET` to store and retrieve an object of this class as follows:

```
var settings = new UserSettings();
settings.EnableNews = True;
....
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings, Formatting.Indented);

//store it to file settings.json for example

//when you want to edit it you can load the file to string
string json_string = File.ReadAllText("file_path");

//then convert json string to model back to edit and read it
UserSettings userSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserSettings>(json_string);
```

for more details read [Newtonsoft Json Package samples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)